# saving data in conversations with Actions on Google

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am developing an app on Actions on Google and I've noticed that when using the [Dialogflow Fulfillment library](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-nodejs) I can't save data between conversations.
Here is the code using the WebhookClient:

```
const { WebhookClient, Card, Suggestion } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
exports.aog_app = functions.https.onRequest((request, response)=>{
  let agent = new WebhookClient({request, response});
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', (agent)=>{
    agent.add("hello there!") ;
  });
  intentMap.set('presentation', (agent)=>{
    let conv = agent.conv();
    let counter = conv.data.counter;
    console.log("counter", counter)
    if(counter){
      conv.data.counter = counter+1;
    }else{
      conv.data.counter = 1;
    }
    agent.add("counter is "+counter) ;
  });
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap)
});
```

`counter` remains undefined on each turn.

But when using the [Action on Google Nodejs Library](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) I can save data without issues:

```
const {
  dialogflow,
  SimpleResponse,
  BasicCard,
  Permission,
  Suggestions,
  BrowseCarousel,
  BrowseCarouselItem,
  Button,
  Carousel,
  DateTime,
  Image,
  DialogflowConversation
} = require('actions-on-google');
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv)=>{
  conv.ask("hello there!");
});
app.intent('presentation', (conv)=>{
  let counter = conv.data.counter;
  console.log("counter", counter)
  if(counter){
    conv.data.counter = counter+1;
  }else{
    conv.data.counter = 1;
  }
  conv.ask("counter is "+counter)

})
exports.aog_app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

`counter` is incremented on each turn.

Is there a way to save data between conversations using the Dialogflow fulfillment library?

Comment: I see you are suing conv.data which is saving data only during conversation. For saving data across conversations you should use conv.user.storage

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data#save_data_across_conversations

Comment: It is the same, conv.user.storage works when using AOG NodeJs library, but not when using Dialogflow Fulfillment library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the `conv` back to agent after you update the `conv.data`

```
agent.add(conv);
```

Comment: If I add that code after ```agent.add("counter is "+counter) ;```  I get the following error: Error: No response has been set. Is this being used in an async call that was not returned as a promise to the intent handler?

Comment: try adding the text directly into `conv` too `conv.ask("counter is " + counter);`

Answer (score 0):

Google's Dialogflow team published a code sample showing how to implement data persistence by integrating Google Cloud's Firebase Cloud Firestore.

You can find the sample here: https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-firestore-nodejs

This is (probably) the code you're looking for:

```
  function writeToDb (agent) {
    // Get parameter from Dialogflow with the string to add to the database
    const databaseEntry = agent.parameters.databaseEntry;

    // Get the database collection 'dialogflow' and document 'agent' and store
    // the document  {entry: "<value of database entry>"} in the 'agent' document
    const dialogflowAgentRef = db.collection('dialogflow').doc('agent');
    return db.runTransaction(t => {
      t.set(dialogflowAgentRef, {entry: databaseEntry});
      return Promise.resolve('Write complete');
    }).then(doc => {
      agent.add(`Wrote "${databaseEntry}" to the Firestore database.`);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(`Error writing to Firestore: ${err}`);
      agent.add(`Failed to write "${databaseEntry}" to the Firestore database.`);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware you can store data on a DB, but I thought that using agent.conv() object would be the same as using the conv object while using de AOG library, since agent.conv() returns a DialogflowConversation object. Maybe I misunderstood it.

Comment: And this parameter we are saving in contexts will be lost after the lifespan of context, right?
How can we save data throughout one conversation, just like `conv.data` in case of `actions-on-google` `conversation` object?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to pull in Actions on Google's library? If you're using Dialogflow for Google Assistant fulfillment, that seems pretty useful. With the Actions on Google Node.js client library, conv.data should allow you to instantiate your own variables. For example, conv.data.hello = "Hello world" would store the string "Hello world" inside the hello object in conv.data, allowing you to access that value later in the conversation. Does that work?